# TensorFlow: What is wrong with my fibonacci sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, fibonacci

I am trying to learn TensorFlow, so I wanted to write a fibonacci sequence (part of it, ofc).

This exercise was inspired by the IBM cognitive class.

Here is my code:

```
#import stuff
import tensorflow as tf

# define the first 2 terms of the sequence
a = tf.Variable(0)
b = tf.Variable(1)

# define the next term. By definition it is the sum of the previous ones
newterm = tf.add(a,b)     # or newterm = a+b

# define the update operations. I want a to become b, and b to become the new term
update1 = tf.assign(a, b)
update2 = tf.assign(b, newterm)

# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# run
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    fibonacci = [a.eval(), b.eval()]
    for i in range(10):
         new, up1, up2 = sess.run([newterm, update1, update2])
         fibonacci.append(new)
    print(fibonacci)
```

However this prints `[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 24, 48, 96, 144, 240, 480]`. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am just creating the next term, and then making `a` the same as `b` and `b` the same as the `newterm`.

Comment: I rejected the edit corresponding to removing "TensorFlow" from the title because I can write a fibonacci sequence in straight python. However I still don't understand how TF works properly, thus  my question here.

Comment: Isn't tensorflow a machine learning tool? I don't know that this is how it would 'learn' the fib sequence. I also don't really understand how tensorflow works, but maybe if you train it with the first 10 numbers of the sequence, it will be able to figure out what the next numbers will be?

Comment: @alex yes I think tensorflow is very suitable for machine learning, in particular deep learning (that is why I am trying to learn it! Want to do a master in it in the future). However, before dwelling into the hardcore deep learning, I wanted to understand how the syntax and the mechanism works, so this was my trial. Surely though you could probably learn the sequence with a machine learning method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensorflow describes the computation using a static graph. You first have to define the graph and then execute it.

The graph execution start from the node you put into the `sess.run([var1,var2, ..., vaN])` call: the order of the variables is **meaningless**. Tensorflow graph evaluation starts from a random node and follows each node from the leaf to the root.

Since you want to force a certain order of execution, you have to use  `tf.control_dependencies` to introduce an ordering constraint into the graph and thus for the execution of the operations in a certain order.

Look at how I changed your code to make it work, it should be pretty clear.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# define the first 2 terms of the sequence
a = tf.Variable(0)
b = tf.Variable(1)

# you have to force the order of assigments:
# first execute newterm, then execute update1 and than update2

# define the next term. By definition it is the sum of the previous ones
newterm = tf.add(a,b)     # or newterm = a+b

with tf.control_dependencies([newterm]):
    update1 = tf.assign(a, b)

    # thus, execute update2 after update1 and newterm
    # have been executed

    with tf.control_dependencies([update1]):
        update2 = tf.assign(b, newterm)

# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# run
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    fibonacci = [a.eval(), b.eval()]
    for i in range(10):
         next, up1, up2 = sess.run([newterm, update1, update2])
         fibonacci.append(next)
    print(fibonacci)
```

Comment: wow I had no idea! Thank you! Also, I'm italian too. How's the research environment at Bologna in terms of Deep Learning?

Comment: Also, I do have another question. In the IBM cognitive class, the solution for this exercise is:
`a=tf.Variable(0)
b=tf.Variable(1)
temp=tf.Variable(0)
c=a+b

update1=tf.assign(temp,c)
update2=tf.assign(a,b)
update3=tf.assign(b,temp)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(init_op)
    for _ in range(15):
        print(s.run(a))
        s.run(update1)
        s.run(update2)
        s.run(update3)`
So basically they introduce a new variable which is a sort of placeholder for the sum. Do you have an explanation of why this method works?

Comment: You're welcome. Since my answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted! (also, if you want some information about the research environment @ Bologna, go on my website [you found it in my profile] and contact me in some way outside from stack overflow]).

Comment: They also use 3 different `sess.run` in order to force the order of evaluation from python to tensorflow (but that's not a good practice, it's way better to properly define an order into the graph)